# POS Performance Issue AX 2012 R3

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, microsoft-dynamics, query-performance

I have slowness.

Can anyone review this [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkmcu-Yjb) (PasteThePlan) and tell me what I need to optimize? This is the [actual plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1foWokhW).

That is a part of process to get Customer Info from an application. In a trace I found that query takes a long time. It took about 14 sec and in another POS it took less than 1 sec.

I'm using SQL Server 2016 - Express Edition

Comment: Can you please provide the DDL statement of your view. Also please provide DDL statements for the underlining tables and how many rows exists in each table.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming this is the store database for a Retail POS and not your main AX database you should be fine running it on Express Edition. Since the store database only contains a subset the data necessary for the store to function without a permanent connection to the main system, and transactions should only be kept for the time needed to allow the system to sync to the main database these store databases are usually fairly small.

However, your estimates are way off (now that you posted the actual plan) in this database, which could explain why your query runs better on another POS (assuming you mean that is in a different store/location with another database behind it) if that database happens to have better statistics.

Please see [AX Retail: Retail store maintenance and SQL Express](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2014/01/10/ax-retail-retail-store-maintenance-and-sql-express/) to see how you can schedule maintenance with SQLCMD, but I would suggest you use [Ola Hallengren's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/) instead, [the FAQ](https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html) explains how to set it up on a SQL Server Express instance.

I also think you have customized the `logisticselectronicaddress` table, so you might want to review the indexing on that table, or post the table definition here so we can help you.

Comment: it's POS DB not Main database ,I already Do rebuild indexes and Update  Statistics Daily 
Plan For good performance POS  may help https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkXMZphnW

Comment: @A_A We're going to need more information about your view and table definitions then I'm afraid

Comment: You Can Find in Below link DB backup with zero data 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/730c869635d5f7f5b9ce15b89309ba6420171012112203/156c121d0f63a2c8e278a5b888aef01c20171012112203/b77975

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

The estimates vs actuals are pretty far off on some of the tables, like SQL Server expected 1 row would come back, but over a quarter million came back.

What you'd probably want to start with is taking apart that view, and only joining the specific tables you need - especially since you only want one row out of the hundreds of thousands of rows it's reading.

Also, side note - running Dynamics AX on SQL Server Express Edition (with no parallelism, and 1GB RAM) is going to be bad if it's the main database (the store database shouldn't be a problem).